# How to recover the cutout image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, layers

Hi I am trying an image for website and mobile banner, for website it is going good but for mobile the image seems little incomplete.

[image: Reference Image]

I want to make the baby face complete for mobile view (portrait view)

Comment: You mean other than asking the photographer if they have an uncropped version?

Comment: At first try Photohop's new  Generative Fill. It's a separately installable extension for Photoshop CC 2023. No guarantee of the result!

Comment: @Tetsujin I have taken the image from Shutterstock

Comment: @kexxgem is it a paid extension ?

Comment: @Sumit - The new generative fill is technically not an extension, the functionality is available only in the beta version of Photoshop, and you can't use it for commercial purposes yet any way. You can only try it out, but I wouldn't recommend using it on a stock image anyway, because of copyright issues. Contact the photographer instead, and ask if they have a complete photo that is not cropped.

Comment: That generative fill is *very freaky* - it added a hand as well as completing the face - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUtTK.png

Comment: @Tetsujin - yeah it's quite amazing. I've tried it out too. The possibilities are endless. Can't wait until Adobe officially releases it.